# How to exit the command but not the interpreter?

Tags: command-line, scheme, xfce, stk-scheme-interpreter

I wrote some code in stk like this :

```
STk> (+ 2 3 ]
]] 

||))
```

However, this is wrong. I'm not able to either correct this by going to the previous line or get out of this command. The only way seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but that takes me out of STk and everything I've done in it is gone.

Is there a way I can be inside the interpreter and continue programming without having to exit the interpreter if I've made an error like the one above. My terminal is Xfce4 Terminal 0.6.3.

Comment: Try Ctrl-C, that's commonly used to get back to a prompt.

Comment: @Barmar So Ctrl-C gives me *** Interrupt *** and then I'm just pushed to the next line. Still not getting to a STk prompt. Its a stupid problem, but very irritating. :|

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This worked for an earlier version that I am using.